# ASP.NET Core Web API - FirstOrDefault not giving required result in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Core 5 Web API, I have these models:

```
public abstract class AuditableBaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
}

public class Merchant : AuditableBaseEntity
{
    public string MerchantName { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Then these are the queries:

> Get the UserName of the Logged in User

```
var userName = _userResolverService.GetUserName();
```

> Get the id of the merchant

```
var merchantId = _context.merchants
                         .Where(u => u.UserName == userName)
                         .Select(m => m.Id)
                         .FirstOrDefault();
```

I expect to get the `Id` of a particular merchant using the logged in `UserName`, but I got zero (0) result

When I debut `userName` returns the correct result. The problem is with getting the `merchantId`.

How do I get this resolved?

Thanks

Comment: The default value for `int` is `0`. Cast it to a nullable `.Select(m => (int?)m.Id)` to get null. Seems the merchant does not exists.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt - It now displays null. But the merchant exists

Comment: I doubt that. Have you made a breakpoint to make sure `userName` is what you expect? When you do `_context.merchants.ToList()`, is the `UserName` property filled? If not, you probably have a bad entity configuration.

Comment: Maybe an issue with case sensitivity? Or leading/trailing spaces?

Answer (score 0):

When you execute only a part of your command, what do you get:

```
var merchant = _context.merchants.Where(u => u.UserName == userName).FirstOrDefault();
var merchantId = merchant.Id;
```

If merchant == null, it will then return the default value for int (id), which is 0.

Edit: let me try to make some suggestions why the where clause returns null:

- u.UserName and userName differ in casing (like 'Mike' and 'mike). And if you have case sensitive comparison set on your database server, return will be null. Either set case insensitive comparison on db level, or make sure that u.UserName and userName casing match. SqlLite is by default case sensitive, and SQL Server is not (if my memory serves me well).
- you are targeting a database on a different location than you expect. This is usually the case when you have multiple copies of the database, like development db / production db. Make sure that the database that is being targeted actually has expected merchant.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. You ask a new question (what do you get?) which is better done in comments. And OP already answered that `merchant` should exist. The problem is not the `0` value, it's not getting an expected result. Your code would throw a null reference exception.

Comment: @GertArnold The question was rhetorical, since it is clear that where clause will return null. By splitting the former command into two rows, it will be more clear to the OP where the problem is, by receiving a null reference exception (that was the idea). Why is it returning null, could be different reasons, I will expand my answer to possible causes.

Comment: Well, IMO it's still nothing but a couple of suggestions that are better sorted out in comments before answering.